# Database agnostic jdbc table import/export to files?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, jdbc, dump

Is it at all possible to do database-agnostic table dumps/hydrates? I don't have any complicated constraints. I would also settle for db-specific ways, but the more pure jdbc it is the better (I don't want to resort to impdp/expdp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/).  DBUnit support exporting to a xml file, and importing from a xml file.  Their [faq](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#streaming) has some advice on how to make the export / imports fast, be sure to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

DBUnit looks good, however you probably are not going to beat the vendor tools for import/export. If you are going to be importing or exporting 100,000+ rows it's probably best to use impdp/expdp.

I've also done strange things like building an insert statement from a sql query and then using sqlplus to process.  [select 'insert into table values ( ...'||column||' ...) ]  But i was being lazy and didn't want to create a sqlldr or jdbc insert program.

I've used perl the same way for when i needed larger imports.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small volume of data, some programs (like Aqua Data Studio) can export data as a sequence of SQL 'INSERT' statements.